# Deploying my angular 8 app to github pages: images (assets files) are not appearing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, github-pages

I'm have an angular 8 application and I'm trying to deploy it to [github pages](https://pages.github.com/) following [this](https://pages.github.com/) and [this](https://alligator.io/angular/deploying-angular-app-github-pages/) tutorial. So, I came up with this command:

```
ng build --prod --base-href [personal-url] &&  ngh --dir=dist/personalsite
```

Everything is working fine unless the images are not appearing. The browser is throwing errors to the console indicating that the images do not exist.

I have the images under the `src/assets/images` and, in the html, I'm importing like this:

```
<div class="image">
     <img src="../../assets/images/profile-image.jfif" />
</div>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/angular-7-deploy-to-github-pages-images-assets-7704f3b2005c) that I should define the image path like this:

```
<img src="./assets/images/profile-image.jfif" />
```

The reason is that the `ng build` copies the assets folder to the root of the `dist/personalsite` folder. The content of the `dist/personalsite` is uploaded to the GitHub pages, which means that the folder `assets` will be available on the root of the Github Pages.